# child_changed event firebase

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm kind of new to firebase. I was just trying out some example when I came across some of its event which by the way are pretty cool.

I have saved some data in firebase database which is :

```
 driver
      -KV_Cj7sL6sg6K9E5ifh
         status: "Incomplete"
```

The thing that troubling me is that when a child is updated child_changed event is triggered. When I access it's data  I'm not seeing the key with it.

I have made a node(I think a row is called a node in firebase not sure) in the driver table. When I changed the status of it to complete the **child_changed** event it triggered. And I receive the packet which has been updated. The thing is I want to get the Id(KV_Cj7sL6sg6K9E5ifh) too. But the problem is it's only sending me  status: complete.

This is the code that I have written for child_changed:

```
usersRef.on("child_changed", function(data) {
   var player = data.val();
   console.log(player);
   console.log("The new status is:  "+ player.status);
});
```

Please help me that how will I receive the Id too. Thanks

Comment: Cross-post: https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/876

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get Id child,try below

```
console.log("The new status is:  "+ player.$id);
```

every `Object` returned by `Firebase` contains `$id` attribute

**UPDATED:**

you can get  `id/key` even `Firebase` does not return id among child, try below

```
console.log("The new status is:  "+ data.ref.key); //it will returns -KV_Cj7sL6sg6K9E5ifh


console.log("The new status is:  "+ data.ref.parent.key); //it will returns driver
```

Comment: Zaid it's giving me undefined. Here is how I used it `usersRef.on("child_changed", function(data) {
   var player = data.val();
   console.log("The new status is:  "+ player.status);
   console.log("The new Id is:  "+ player.$id);
}); `

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(player)`?

Comment: Zaid it's undefined

Comment: strange, its giving `console.log(player)` as undefined? then how you are getting status. it must not be undefined

Comment: Zaid player.status gives me complete since I have changed the status from incomplete to complete but the player itself gives me undefined.

Comment: it must print an object on console, not be undefined if it giving you status value. can you provide running code snippet? so I can reproduce your error, or try to clear broswer cache.

Comment: I do not know why that happened but now it's printing a object this is what I'm getting `Player is : [object Object]
`

Comment: @Gardezi just try `console.log(data.val())` what is the output

Comment: Zaid this is what I'm getting on `console.log(data.val())` ==> ` [object Object]
`

Comment: Thanks man you saved me. Can you please tell me why was I not getting the Id before

Comment: firebase events don't gives you Id It just gives child data and you can get child key but key will not included within the child. but Firebase query will gives you Id witnin each returned child.

Answer (score 4):

What you call the id, is called the *key* in Firebase terms. To get the key of a snapshot, you can access the `key` property of that snapshot:

```
usersRef.on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {
   var player = snapshot.val();
   console.log(player);
   console.log("The new status is:  "+ player.status);
   console.log("The key of the player is "+snapshot.key);
})
```

Comment: I know. I tried using the key but that was not working for me. That was what really surprised me due to which I came over here

Comment: Frank it started working for me like you said. I tried to find out what was the problem but was not able to find anything wrong.Restarted my computer and I was getting the key like you told me. Relly weird.

Comment: Good to hear you got it sorted.